# How can I select a product and make it show on stripe checkout session one at a time?

Tags: stripe-payments

So I recently integrated stripe into a website project I am working on. The problem is that when I click a product to add to the cart to checkout it shows all the products, including the prices and total, on the stripe session instead of the item I selected. How can I fix this problem?

I provided my code below:

**server.js**

```
    require("dotenv").config()
    
    // This is your test secret API key.
    const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_XXXXXXXXX');
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    
    const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';
    
   const storeItems = new Map ([
   [1, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Black Sweatsuit" }],
   [2, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Grey Sweatsuit" }],
   [3, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Red Sweatsuit" }],
   [4, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Blue Sweatsuit" }],
   [5, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Black T-Shirt" }],
   [6, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Blue T-Shirt" }],
   [7, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Purple T-Shirt" }],
]);

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: req.body.items,
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
    automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

**checkout.js**

```
  const button = document.getElementById("checkout-button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      items: [
        {id: 1, quantity:5},
        {id: 2, quantity:5},
        {id: 3, quantity:5},
        {id: 4, quantity:5},
        {id: 5, quantity:75},
        {id: 6, quantity:75},
        {id: 7, quantity:75},
      ],
    }),
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) return res.json()
    return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
  })
  .then(({ url }) => {
    window.location = url
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e.error)
  })
})
```

**shop.html**

```
 <!--SHOP-->
   <section class="shop-section">
    <div class="card-wrapper">
           <!--Item 1-->
               <div data-id="1" class="card-item">
                   <img src="images/Shop/IMG-5288.jpg">
                   <div class="details">
                       <h3>Black Sweatsuit</h3>
                       <p>
                           <span>Kingdom</span>
                           
                           <span class="price">Price: $85.00</span>
                           <span class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></span>
                       </p>
                   </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`line_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items) parameter in Checkout Session is for the items purchased. If you would like to include only the selected items, all the prices in `line_items` shouldn't be set.

In `checkout.js`, you've passed `items` that include item IDs and their quantities, which you can retrieve them from the request in `/create-checkout-session` endpoint at `server.js`. For example,

```
const items = req.body.items;
```

There should be item ID to price ID mapping (usually in database) for you to identify the price ID based on the given item ID. An example will be:

| Item ID | Price ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | price_1xxx |
| 2 | price_2xxx |

or

```
const itemToPriceMap = new Map ([
  [1, { priceId: 'price_1xxx' }],
  [2, { priceId: 'price_2xxx' }],
])
```

You can iterate all the selected items and find out its corresponding price ID based on the item ID. For example,

```
const priceId = itemToPriceMap.get(1);
```

With that, the Checkout Session can be created with the price ID selected under `line_items`.

Comment: So I'm getting an error saying that the "items" in req.body.items aren't defined. I don't know if it's how I am coding it but I am going to update my code right now

Comment: I uploaded the edits above, I replaced the line_items with the code your provided